# Как сделать проверку значения из базы данных?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть база данных на `sqlite`

В ней хранятся такие данные: `id`, `money`

Хочу сделать игру 'Угадай число', почти все готово, осталось: сделать проверку money, чтобы пользователь не смог ввести ставку больше чем его баланс в базе данных

Не могу понять, как сделать эту проверку

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('baza.sqlite')
# q = connection.cursor()
userid = str(message.chat.id)
q.execute('select money from users where Id = ' + userid)
```

Comment: Проверка нужна на уровне `python`, или `sql`?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо сделать запрос

```
SELECT money
FROM tablename
WHERE id = user_id
```

В свою очередь user_id должно передаваться вместе с запросом ставки

Answer (score 0):

Вот образец:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3

def init_db(data, name):  # Инициализация пустой базы.
    if Path(name).is_file():
        return None
    conn = sqlite3.connect(name)
    q = conn.cursor()
    q.execute('CREATE TABLE users(id INT, money REAL)')
    for i in data:
        q.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)', i)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

db_path = '/tmp/baza.sqlite'

init_db([(1, 10.1),
         (2, 12.2),
         (3, 13.3),
        ], db_path)  # Инициализация пустой базы.

# Далее сама проверка.    
userid = 2
bet = 13
connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
q = connection.cursor()
q.execute('SELECT money FROM users WHERE id = ?', (userid,))
row = q.fetchone()
print(f'На счете: {row}')

if row is None:
    print(f'Нет информации о пользователе: {userid}')
elif bet <= row[0]:
    print(f'Ставка {bet} - принята')
else:
    print(f'Ставка {bet} - отклонена')
conn.close()
```

Comment: Не работает, все равно можно делать ставки больше чем в базе. имею код: q.execute('select amount from users where Id = ' + userid)
 row = q.fetchone()
 connection.commit()
 bet = message.text  # Ставка, сделанная пользователем.
 if bet <= row[0]: